# How to not manually limit PageSize

Tags: c#

I am trying to understand how PageSize works on the bottom code.

Bottom is code that retrieves data, and it currently has a manual page size setup as "PageSize = 1000" (line 7).

Apparently, there is about 900+ but less than 1000 data to retrieve.

Whenever actual data output is less than the page size (this case: 1000), there is no data output (blank output).

**How do we change the code so that I do not have to worry about PageSize?**

```
public static string Run(ILogger logger)       
    {
        OnlineClient client = Bootstrap.Client(logger);
        ReadByQuery query = new ReadByQuery()
        {
            ObjectName = "CONTACT",
            PageSize = 1000,
            Fields =
            {
                "RECORDNO"
            }

        };
        logger.LogInformation("Executing query to Intacct API");
        Task<OnlineResponse> task = client.Execute(query);
        task.Wait();   
        
        OnlineResponse response = task.Result;
        Result result = response.Results[0];
        LogManager.Flush();

        int i = 1;
        while (result.NumRemaining > 0 && i <= 1 && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.ResultId))
            {
            i++;
            ReadMore more = new ReadMore()
            {
                ResultId = result.ResultId
            };
            dynamic resultJson =   
                   JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result.Data));  
            string resultJsonString = resultJson.ToString();

            return resultJsonString;
            }
        return "";
    }
```

There is a property (getter and setter) of this object (ReadByQuery) as follows:

But, this is code from a library so I cannot modify.

```
public class ReadByQuery : AbstractFunction
{
    public List<string> Fields;
    public IQuery Query;

    public ReadByQuery(string controlId = null);

    public string ObjectName { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    public string DocParId { get; set; }

    public override void WriteXml(ref IaXmlWriter xml);
}
```

Comment: This seems to be a question about a specific API, not a C# question. You'll most likely have to take this up with the API provider.

Comment: @Corey Thanks for your feedback. Given the limitation that I can control the API, is there any way I could modify the code? Isn't it just retrieving the data?

Comment: It's not about controlling the API, it's about understanding it. You'll have to figure out how the API handles paging, counting and so on and then write your code to work with that API. This is not a C# question at all because the equivalent code would fail in the same way in *any* language. Ask the API provider, or read their documentation. We can't help you.

Comment: this is unrelated to your question, but please make your method a static Async Task<string> and then await your tasks properly. Also .Result implicitly calls .Wait() so you don't need to do both (but please don't use either unless you have to, using 'var response = await client.Execute(query);' is so much cleaner, safer and potentially more performant)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up modifying the C# code as below:

I commented out where it has the PageSize, and now it populates the whole data fine.

The major portion that made it work was changing from 'While' to 'If' and then I used "result.Count" instead of "reuslt.NumRemaining".

```
public static string Run(ILogger logger)       
    {
        OnlineClient client = Bootstrap.Client(logger);
        ReadByQuery query = new ReadByQuery()
        {
            ObjectName = "CONTACT",
            Fields =
             {
                "RECORDNO",
             }

                        };
        Task <OnlineResponse> task = client.Execute(query);

        OnlineResponse response = task.Result;
        Result result = response.Results[0];
        LogManager.Flush();

        if (result.Count > 0)
            {
            dynamic resultJson =   
                   JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result.Data));  
            string resultJsonString = resultJson.ToString();

            return resultJsonString;
            }
        return "";
    }
```